# EventEmitter or ReplaySubject not working from service

Tags: angular

Using ng9 I have a service that checks  resource use.  I want this to fire an event so I can have a generic dialog to inform the user.  The service will be called from lots of places, like when saving a record.

Problem is, if never seems to fire the event or observable (Ive tried both).  Im thinking it's because this is triggerd from inside a pipe maybe?

Service:

```
  private _limitExceeded = new ReplaySubject<LimitExceededEvent>(1);
  limitExceeded$ = this._limitExceeded.asObservable();

  ...

   checkResourceUsage(code: string): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.getLimits(code).pipe(
        map(limits => {

          if (limits) {
            const ev = new LimitExceededEvent();
            this._limitExceeded.next(ev);

            return false;
          }

          // no limits? not possible ? lets assume so and be kind to people
          return true;
        }));
   }
```

Component:

```
  if (this.form.valid) {
     this.limitsService.checkResourceLimit(Resources.Thing).subscribe((ok) => {
       if(ok) {
          .. go ahead and save it
```

App listener:

```
this.limitsService.limitExceeded$
  .subscribe((ev: LimitExceededEvent) => 
     this.dialog.open(LimitExceededDialogComponent, { data: ev }));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the `getLimits` function returns an observable but you do not subscribe to it. That could be the reason reason the code in the `pipe` is never executed.

Comment: getLimits is wrapped by limitservice.checkResourceUsage.  I can see it's working and I can set a breakpoint on this._limitExceeded.next() and see it executes.  I just never get the subscription executed on the limitExceeded$ subject.

Comment: Are you sure that you are subscribing to getLimits?

Comment: @Jonesie the current code you wrote obviously works, I suggest you make a stackblitz where you can reproduce your issue. If I would make an educated guess, I would say you have not provided the service correctly, and it has multiple instances. You can check if that's the case by placing a `console.log` in the service constructor. Make sure you do not add the service to any providers array of any module or component, and just use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` as service annotation